# Issue in getting text content (php)

Tags: php, text, combobox

i'm actually working on Ubuntu distribution, coding php.

I want to read a text file, and extract lines so that they appear in a combobox field.

I'm trying to do it this way : (i'm new in php, be gentle :d)

```
$file = fopen($fichier_txt.'.txt', 'r+');

if ($file) 
{
    $compteur_lignes = 0;
    while (!feof($file) /*&& ($buffer = fgets($file, 4096) !== false)*/)
    {
        $lignes = fgets($file);
        echo '<br>';
        echo $lignes;
        $compteur_lignes++;
    }
    echo '<br>';
    $lignes = fgets($file);
    echo '<select name="cbBox" size="1" id="Combobox">';
    $option = "<option value=\"Please select a Category\">Select an option</option> \n";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $compteur_lignes; $i++)
    {

        $option .= "<option ";
        $option .= "value=\"$lignes[$i]\">$lignes[$i]</option> \n";
    }
    echo $option;
    echo '</select>';

fclose($file);
}
```

As I do this, i get the content of my text file in my localhost output, but my comboxo shows empty fields, like if my $lignes[$i] doesn't contain any value...

Would you mind helping me a little :) ?

Thanks in advance,

Regards,

Stelio Kontos.

Comment: Have you checked `file_get_contents`?

Comment: Yep, but it wasn't appropriate since I wanted to get text as an array and not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not filling `$lignes` as an array but as a string, which means that it always contains only the last line. You should be doing this:

```
$lignes = array();
while (!feof($file))
{
    $lignes[] = fgets($file);
    echo '<br>';
    echo $lignes[count($lignes) - 1];
    $compteur_lignes++;
}
```

And you have to remove the `$lignes = fgets($file)` that is outside your loop.

By the way, the variable `$compteur_lignes` is useless, you can get the size of the `$lignes` array at any time using the function `count`:

```
$lines_count = count($lignes);
```

As a side note that is slightly offtopic, I'd recommend naming your variables in english rather than french. PHP functions and keywords are in english, you should code in english.

Comment: Ow, indeed ! I did as you said, and it does work :).

Regarding my $compteur_lignes, i tried with count() but as I was reading in string, my count was always equals to 1...

And I do name my variables in english, but I already had english names for these variables (for some testing), so I forgot to put it back in order, my bad !

Thanks a lot anyway, you made my day !

Answer (score 1):

I agree with AntonieB's answer but the code needs to be modified little more in order to work. Please try this:

```
$file = fopen($fichier_txt.'.txt', 'r+');

if ($file) 
{
    $lignes = array();
    while (!feof($file) /*&& ($buffer = fgets($file, 4096) !== false)*/)
    {
        $lignes[] = fgets($file);
        echo '<br>';
        echo end($lignes);
    }
    $lignes_count = count($lignes);
    echo '<select name="cbBox" size="1" id="Combobox">';
    $option = "<option value=\"Please select a Category\">Select an option</option> \n";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $lignes_count; $i++)
    {

        $option .= "<option ";
        $option .= "value=\"$lignes[$i]\">$lignes[$i]</option> \n";
    }
    echo $option;
    echo '</select>';

fclose($file);
}
```

*I hope it helps*

Comment: I did modify my code using the : echo end($lignes); instead of : echo $lines[count($lines) - 1];  and I get the same result, I saw that end function puts the cursor at the end of my array, but i'm not sure to understand the necessity of use ? It works fine tho, thanks :).

Comment: end() and count() both does the trick.
But end($lignes); is faster than using count function and then accessing the element from array as per returned last index( $lines[count($lines) - 1]; ). You code will execute faster if your file is having many lines. For small size files(with less new lines) you will not even notice the difference.

Comment: No Problem. Happy Coding!